# Proximal Operator to Sum of Norm Functions

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, proximal-operators

The proximal operator is defined by:
$$ prox_{\tau f} = \arg\min_u \frac 1 {2\tau} \|u-u^k\|^2 + f(u) $$

I know the solution when 
$$ f(u) = \|Au+b\|_1 $$

But I wonder how to derive the solution of proximal operator when
$$ f(u) = \|Au+b\|_1 + \|Bu+c\|_1$$

Comment: Just an idea: Could'nt you write as new $\bar{u}=(u,u)$ and then just consider the objective $\frac{1}{4\tau}\|\bar{u}-(u^{k},u^{k})\|^{2}+\|C\bar{u}+d\|_{1}$ where the matrix or operator $C$ is now acting as a diagonal operator $(A,0;0,B)$ and $d=(b,c)? This new problem is now exactly of the form you can solve...and with that solution you should obtain also the solution for the original problem.

Comment: Do you _really_ know the solution for $\|Au+b\|_1$? Because there should be no analytic solution in that case.

Comment: The second $f$ is basically identical to the first, since
$$\|Au+b\|_1+\|Bu+c\|_1 = \left\|\begin{bmatrix} A \\ B \end{bmatrix} u + \begin{bmatrix} b \\ c \end{bmatrix}\right\|$$